# Changing domains and Google Analytics

Tags: domains, google-analytics, 301-redirect

My website has moved from `example.com` to `example2.com` and now I have two questions:

1. Although all pages in `example.com` are being 301 redirected to `example2.com`, why are my users now about 50% of the old user count?
2. Do I need to create a new Google Analytics property for the new site?

It seems that old parameters (for the old site) is working but it's a little strange that in these 5 days that I have moved the site the number of users are less but the monthly number of visitors and unique visitors are increasing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**`1. Although all pages in example.com are being 301 redirected to example2.com, why are my users now about 50% of old user count?`**

If you're using the same tracking code and *all* pages have been redirected properly, the lower numbers you're seeing are likely due to a change in search engine results because your domain has changed.

This is to be expected, and will take some time to regain your previous search engine results while the search engines build trust for your new site. Here are some things that should help with this:

- Check to make sure that you don't have any internal links to the old page in your content or sitemap, and if so change them to the new URL.
- Check for external links in Google Webmaster Tools, and if possible, try to contact the webmaster of the referring site to change them to the new URL.
- Re-submit your updated sitemap to Google Webmaster Tools, and other search engines.
- Use the "Fetch As Google" function in Google Webmaster Tools so that Google will re-crawl and index your site. See this for more information on that:
  [Ask Google to crawl a page or site](https://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1352276)
- Let search engines know that your site has moved using the steps listed in these:

  [Tell Google when your site moves](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/83106?hl=en)

  [Bing - Site Move](http://www.bing.com/webmaster/help/how-to-use-the-site-move-tool-bb8f5112)

**`2. Do I need to create a new Google Analytics property for the new site?`**

You don't need to create a new property, however, you should update the domain in your URL's within Google Analytics. Here's how:

- Select the property for the old domain from your Account Home page.
- Click `Admin` from the top-right corner of the page and select
  `Property Settings`.
- Edit the `Default URL` from: `http://example.com` to
  `http://example2.com`, and click `Apply`.

**`...in these 5 days that I have moved the site the number of users are less but the monthly number of visitors and unique visitors are increasing.`**

That is to be expected too - since the domain is new, visitors who visited your previous site are now unique to your new site.